# i need assistants, a button should work 4 two possibilities from a combo box with specific lines but only really works for option 1

Tags: python, python-3.4, tk-toolkit

I setup a button to work with two possibilities from a combo box so that if Event 1 is chosen it will save to lines 1 to 4 which works fine and saves with no problems but when Event 2 is chosen it should save 5 to 8 but it doesn't work correctly the 5 will place its self in corrected line but 6 will fly of like 10 lines down, i spent yesterday adding and removing code but no gold.any ideas?

```
def saveteam():
    with open("data/tournamentdatae1.txt",'r') as f:
        get_all=f.readlines()
        event = combo_event.get()
    if event == 'Event 1':
        with open("data/tournamentdatae1.txt",'r+') as f:
            for i,line in enumerate(get_all,1):         
                if i == 1:                 
                    input1 = team_1.get()
                    f.writelines(input1)
                    f.writelines("\n")
            for i,line in enumerate(get_all,1):         
                if i == 2:                 
                    input2 = team_2.get()
                    f.writelines(input2)
                    f.writelines("\n")
            for i,line in enumerate(get_all,1):         
                if i == 3:                 
                    input3 = team_3.get()
                    f.writelines(input3)
                    f.writelines("\n")
            for i,line in enumerate(get_all,1):         
                if i == 4:                 
                    input4 = team_4.get()
                    f.writelines(input4)
                    f.writelines("\n")
    if event == 'Event 2':
        with open("data/tournamentdatae1.txt",'r+') as f:
            for i,line in enumerate(get_all,1):         
                if i == 5:                 
                    input1 = team_1.get()
                    f.writelines(input1)
                    f.writelines("\n")
                else:
                    f.writelines(line)
            for i,line in enumerate(get_all,1):         
                if i == 6:                 
                    input2 = team_2.get()
                    f.writelines(input2)
                    f.writelines("\n")
                else:
                    f.writelines(line)
```

this is what i do but not sure how to make show work with this

```
         if event == 'Event 1':
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 1':
          get_all[20] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 2':
          get_all[21] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 3':
          get_all[22] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 4':
          get_all[23] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 5':
          get_all[24] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 6':
          get_all[25] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 7':
          get_all[26] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 8':
          get_all[27] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 9':
          get_all[28] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 10':
          get_all[29] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 11':
          get_all[30] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 12':
          get_all[31] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 13':
          get_all[32] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 14':
          get_all[33] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 15':
          get_all[34] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 16':
          get_all[35] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 17':
          get_all[36] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 18':
          get_all[37] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 19':
          get_all[38] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 20':
          get_all[39] = individual.get() + "\n"
 if event == 'Event 2':
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 1':
          get_all[40] = individual.get() + "\n"
      if indivcombo == 'Individual 2':
          get_all[41] = individual.get() + "\n"
```

Comment: All those `for` loops make no sense. If you just want the element where `i == 1` (or 2, or 3, etc.), just use `getall[1]`. Also, `line` is not even used, so you could just check `if len(getall) >= 1: ...` Or do you want to _overwrite_ those lines in the file? Not really clear.

Comment: sorry im not sure what u mean, i use getall and only use line and when i want it to carry on reading the lines in the files . u got any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: i want to have a button which when clicked will check what is selected in a combo box and will save to different lines in a text file depending on what is chosen in a combo box. any ideas

Comment: @tobias_k Because of the **1** in `enumerate(get_all,1)`, we would want `get_all[0]` rather than `get_all[1]`

Comment: whats the difference between the 0 and 1

Comment: @Nelson Right, but that does not really matter, does it?

Comment: You read _all_ the lines into `getall`, then open the file again without reading. You will then add all the new lines at the beginning of the file, no matter in which iteration of the loop you write. I'd suggest replacing the data in the `getall` list and then overwriting the file with the updated data, but again, I'm not really sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: so where would i have to 0??

Comment: @tobias_k No, just thought I'd make sure OP doesn't introduce an OBOB.

Comment: i want to have a button which when clicked will check what is selected in a combo box and will save to different lines in a text file depending on what is chosen in a combo box so option 1 will save to lines 1 to 5 and option 2 will save line 5 to 8. any ideas option 1 works fine so Event 1 is fine but Event 2 doesnt work

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the code must edit an upper and lower section of a file? Are you sure you can't just append to the file and parse it when you need the data? Can you split it into 2 different files for `Event 1` and `Event 2`? Does the data even have to be written to a file?

Comment: And to answer your earlier question, @Jackichan, about the 0 and 1, python indexing starts at 0, so to access the first element of a list you want `get_all[0]`. `enumerate(get_all,1)` is essentially forcing python to start indexing at 1.

Comment: its a tournament score system so it has to save data and then retrieve it , there will be 5 events and 4 teams which is why u have 4 x 5 bits of data as the data will be saved as the tournament progresses which is why i used combo boxes for the events and then 4 boxes for each team i want it so there is one button that works for each event and saving to set lines allows me to get the correct data back later, data will later be saved and retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (big if), then you want to replace certain lines in the file with values from the `team_X` variables. The way you are doing it, you read the entire file into `get_all` (a list not longer connected to the file), then re-open the file in `r+` mode, then iterate that list (but not the file!) until you get the line you want to overwrite, then write to the newly opened file.

This should not work, as the newly opened file is still at the first line, even as you loop the list.

Instead, I'd suggest replacing the values directly in the list, and overwriting the entire file with `'w'`.

```
def saveteam():
    filename = "data/tournamentdatae1.txt"
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        get_all = f.readlines()

    event = combo_event.get()
    if event == 'Event 1':
        get_all[0] = team_1.get() + "\n"
        get_all[1] = team_2.get() + "\n"
        get_all[2] = team_3.get() + "\n"
        get_all[3] = team_4.get() + "\n"

    if event == 'Event 2':    
        get_all[4] = team_1.get() + "\n"
        get_all[5] = team_2.get() + "\n"
        get_all[6] = team_3.get() + "\n"
        get_all[7] = team_4.get() + "\n"            

    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for line in get_all:
            f.write(line)
```

You could further reduce code duplication (particularly if there are more "events" like these) by putting the lines to replace and the corresponding team variables into a list and a dict of lists, and then zipping and looping those lists:

```
def saveteam():
    filename = "data/tournamentdatae1.txt"
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        get_all = f.readlines()

    team_vars = [team_1, team_2, team_3, team_4]    
    lines = {"Event 1": [0, 1, 2, 3], "Event 2": [4, 5, 6, 7]}

    event = combo_event.get()
    for team, line in zip(team_vars, lines.get(event, [])):
        get_all[line] = team.get() + "\n"

    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for line in get_all:
            f.write(line)
```

Note: I did not test any of this.

---

Analogeously for reading teams from file. (Note: I moved the list and dict out of the method as it's always the same and this way it can be reused for both reading and writing teams.)

```
team_vars = [team_1, team_2, team_3, team_4]    
lines = {"Event 1": [0, 1, 2, 3], "Event 2": [4, 5, 6, 7]}
filename = "data/tournamentdatae1.txt"

def showteam():
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        get_all = f.readlines()

    event = combo_event.get()
    for team, line in zip(team_vars, lines.get(event, [])):
        team.set(get_all[line].strip())
```

Comment: if this works man then u will save me a lot of time as there has to be 5 events so a lot of code my way , plus my code works for event 1 just not 2 will give your way a go.

Comment: its a tournament score system so it has to save data and then retrieve it , there will be 5 events and 4 teams which is why u have 4 x 5 bits of data as the data will be saved as the tournament progresses which is why i used combo boxes for the events and then 4 boxes for each team i want it so there is one button that works for each event and saving to set lines allows me to get the correct data back later, data will later be saved and retrieved.

Comment: Mate thank you so much if only u came to me 3 days earlier this program would be done, but this will make the code so much cleaner your great, thanks so much

Comment: i have one question , do you have a better idea for retrieving this data currently i have this

Comment: def show_team():
    with open("data/tournamentdatae1.txt",'r') as f:
     event = combo_event.get()
     if event == 'Event 1': 
            with open('data/tournamentdatae1.txt', 'r') as f:
               for i,line in enumerate(f,1):
                    if i == 1: 
                         team_1txt.insert(0.0, line)
            with open('data/tournamentdatae1.txt', 'r') as f:
               for i,line in enumerate(f,1):

Comment: @Jackichan Just read the lines to a list and then index the elements in the list directly. Also, use the `set` method of the team variables. See my update.

Comment: how would that work for all events ?? i will insert my current code into yours as comments  have char limit

Comment: @Jackichan Please add your updated code to your question (append to, don't replace the original code!)

Comment: @Jackichan Have you tried my code for `showteam`? Does it not work? There might be a few small bugs, as I could not really test any of this without writing a full-flung tournament UI from scratch, but it should work. If you have more events, just add those to the `lines` dictionary. Note that the line-number start with `0` here, not with `1`.

Comment: i tried this for a new set of data which uses two combo boxes so how do i do this for show but with two combo boxes something like this.

Comment: if event == 'Event 1':
              if indivcombo == 'Individual 1':
                  get_all[20] = individual.get() + "\n"
              if indivcombo == 'Individual 2':
                  get_all[21] = individual.get() + "\n"

Comment: u can find this at the top too